# PS2 screen blackout with Component Cable

Tags: ps2

I have a problem with my PS2 (SCPH-50003) - when I connect it to my TV (Samsung LE32B450), I get random screen blackouts. The screen turns black and apparantly switches video modes, then after a few seconds it returns back to the game. This behaviour is more frequent as the console warms up, as it does not happen until first 20 minutes into the game.

I think it's not caused by the cable or the console, because the PS2 was working fine with this cable for hours hooked up to my friend's TV. Everything is working fine with a component cable. Do you know what could I do to alleviate my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar issues with older game consoles attached to my projector with long cable runs.  Your TV will attempt to switch to another input if it doesn't detect a high enough signal on the current input.

Your PS2 could be getting old and the video output power may fluctuate too much to maintain a consistent signal on your digital TV.  On older analog televisions, you probably wouldn't even notice this (the picture might just get dim momentarily).  I would guess that your friend's tv is analog?

A few things you might try.

1. See if your TV has a "signal lock" option.  This will prevent it from automatically searching other inputs when it *thinks* it loses the signal.  I tried looking up the manual for your television on Samsung's website but I could not find the LE32B450 listed.
2. Try to minimize any extension cables you might be using.  The longer your cable, the more power you will lose.